# Splunk MITRE Valid Account Case

Tags: splunk-query

I am working on Valid Account MITRE use case which EvenCode is 4624. The case is as this:  Valid Accounts on events which are detected by *** when the event(s) were detected by one or more of**** AND when any of these with the same source IP more than 1 time, across more than 5 destination IP within 1 minutes. Below is the query I came up with, I wonder if this is correct? Thanks in advance

```
(index=* OR index=*)(source=* (eventcode="4624")) src_ip="*" dest_ip="*" | evenstats dc(src_ip) as src_ip dc(dest_ip) as dest_ip|search src_ip>1 dest_ip> 5 |bin span=1m _time
```

Here is my reasons to query:

- I am using evenstats dc(src_ip) to aggregate the distinct count of src_ip and then filter it by the src_ip that is greater than 1.
- I am also using evenstats dc(dest_ip) to aggregate the disctinct count of dest_ip and then filter it by the dest_ip that is greather than 1.
- Finally I am using |bin span = 1m _time  to to search within 1 minute time span.